# How can i run 6 processes in parallel using mpirun?

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi

i got this error

```
It seems that [at least] one of the processes that was started with
mpirun did not invoke MPI_INIT before quitting (it is possible that
more than one process did not invoke MPI_INIT -- mpirun was only
notified of the first one, which was on node n0).
```

while i used MPI for running 6 processes as i have 6 cores only in parallel using this command

```
mpirun -np 6 my_command
```

laptop with 2060 RTX

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your code don't call the `MPI_Init()` function.
Maybe you could share your code or reproduce the error on the simple hello world (ex [here](https://mpitutorial.com/tutorials/mpi-hello-world/))?